# Adding a filter to criteria - weird result

Tags: shopware6

I'm trying to filter children of a given parent, searching for all children with certain `optionId` value. This is the base criteria:

```
        $criteria = new Criteria();
        $criteria
            ->addAssociation('configuratorSettings.option')
            ->addAssociation('configuratorSettings.option.media')
            ->addAssociation('configuratorSettings.option.group')
            ->addAssociation('media')
            ->addAssociation('options.group')
            ->addAssociation('options.variant')
            ->addAssociation('children')
            ->addAssociation('children.cover')
            ->addAssociation('children.optionIds')
            ->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('id', $id));
```

This is fine (all children are returned), if I add the following:

```
$criteria->addFilter(new ContainsFilter('children.optionIds.', $additionalFilter));
```

I get a weird error `Unknown column 'product.children.product_version_id' in 'field list'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tried also
    ->addAssociation('children.options')
    $criteria->addFilter(new ContainsFilter('children.options.id', $additionalFilter));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trailing `.` at `children.optionIds.`.
Adding `children.optionIds` to the associations is not necessary, since it is not an association field.

This is not reproducible on recent versions, you can [run the code here on `6.5.1.0`](https://shopware.foo/uunA4rg48c). Which version is this happening with? If this is an older version, it could've been fixed since.

Alternatively you could try fetching the children by their `parentId`. Since you already seem to have the `id` of the parent, you might not need to fetch the parent again or you could fetch it separately.

```php
$parentCriteria = new Criteria([$parentId]);
$parentCriteria
    ->addAssociation('configuratorSettings.option')
    ->addAssociation('configuratorSettings.option.media')
    ->addAssociation('configuratorSettings.option.group')
    ->addAssociation('media');
    
// ...

$childCriteria = new Criteria();
$childCriteria
    ->addAssociation('cover')
    ->addAssociation('options.group')
    ->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('parentId', $parentId));
```

The parent itself shouldn't have options, only the children should have options associated.

Futhermore the use of `ContainsFilter` also depends on what kind of value `$additionalFilter` has. `ContainsFilter` is generally more of a string comparison, as it matches the occurrence of a string inside the value of a text field. While it does work for JSON fields, it would likely be more appropriate to use `EqualsFilter` or `EqualsAnyFilter` for matching one ore more ids in a list of ids.

```php
// match multiple id in `optionIds`
$childCriteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('optionIds', '897d277ce0b14eeda39221c940d4d285'));

// match multiple ids in `optionIds`
$childCriteria->addFilter(new EqualsAnyFilter('optionIds', ['897d277ce0b14eeda39221c940d4d285', 'eef28122c13c4b178cf275e0f30da49b']));
```

Comment: OT: wow, there is a Shopware fiddle? Who made that :-) ?

Comment: Me  Still in sort of a trial phase to see what can break and how well it is received. If all goes well I'll eventually do some polishing.